# Limit CPU usage in PHP

Tags: php, apache, server

As there is the variable memory_limit, is there any that allows me to limit the use of php cpu?

in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 128M

cpu_limit = ????
```

Comment: `nice(1)` on unix-like OSs

Comment: Can you find one [in the PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.php)?

Comment: No, php does not have a way to limit cpu. You would need you container-ize your application then limit the container.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "limit the use of the CPU" - Do you mean limit the total running time? Do you mean limit the CPU percentage used? Do you mean limit the priority of the process?

Comment: Why is that important? Write your script and let it run. If it takes too long time to execute in your opinion begin to optimize the code. Maybe think of multi threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so, so far as I know there is no option inside the php config file that enables you to set that just like you would do for memory limit but I do know  you can set the maximum execution time for a script from the PHP config file 
or that when running on linux or unix based system you can limit the CPU usage of a specific user.
So in your case you might have to find out what user your php processes are being run as and then set the limit for that user.
So mainly to answer your question...

NO, there is no such variable that allows you to limit the use of php cpu in php.ini.

but if incase you are interested in limiting user as I said 
you could check out these posts to get started [here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups) , [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-limit-the-cpu-usage-per-user-715490/), and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage)